# Build tree using python

Tags: python, tree

I am new to python and trying to build a tree with parent -child relation using python. I am facing hard time to make it:

Data frame:

```
data = [['root','Parent1','Children1','Grand Childern 1','Great Grand Childern 1'],['root','Parent1','Children2','Grand Childern 1','Great Grand Childern 1'],['root','Parent1','Children2','Grand Childern 2','Great Grand Childern 1'],['root','Parent2','Children1','Grand Childern 1','Great Grand Childern 1'],['root','Parent2','Children2','Grand Childern 1','Great Grand Childern 1']]

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['LEVEL 1','LEVEL 2','LEVEL 3','LEVEL 4','LEVEL 5'])
```

And I am trying to convert as JSON tree format like below:

```
{
"name": "root",
"children": [{ 
    "name": "Parent1",
    "children": [{ 
        "name": "Children1" ,
        "children":[{
            "name":"Grand Children1",
            "children":[{
                "name":"Great Grand Children1"
                }]
            }]},
    { 
        "name": "Children2" , 
        "children":[{
          "name":"Grand Children1",
                "children":[{"name":"Great Grand Children1"}],
          "name":"Grand Children2",
                "children":[{"name":"Great Grand Children1"}]}
          ] }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "name": "Parent2",
    "children": [
      { 
          "name": "Children1" ,
          "children":[{"name":"Grand Children1",
                        "children":[{"name":"Great Grand Children1"}]}] },
      { 
          "name": "Children2" , 
          "children":[{
          "name":"Grand Children1","children":[{"name":"Great Grand Children1"}],
          "name":"Grand Children1","children":[{"name":"Great Grand Children2"}]}
          ] }
    ]
  }]
}
```

DataFrame:

[image]

I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: It would be good to show you where your code stands, and explain exactly what doesn't work with it. Otherwise, it would look like you want us to do the work for you, which we of course won't do!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use recursion with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def to_tree(d):
   _d = defaultdict(list)
   for a, *b in d:
      _d[a].append(b)
   return [{'name':a, 'children':to_tree(k)} if (k:=list(filter(None, b))) else \
                    {'name':a} for a, b in _d.items()]

data = [['root','Parent1','Children1','Grand Childern 1','Great Grand Childern 1'],['root','Parent1','Children2','Grand Childern 1','Great Grand Childern 1'],['root','Parent1','Children2','Grand Childern 2','Great Grand Childern 1'],['root','Parent2','Children1','Grand Childern 1','Great Grand Childern 1'],['root','Parent2','Children2','Grand Childern 1','Great Grand Childern 1']]
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(to_tree(data), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Parent1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Children1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Grand Childern 1",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Great Grand Childern 1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Children2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Grand Childern 1",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Great Grand Childern 1"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Grand Childern 2",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Great Grand Childern 1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Children1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Grand Childern 1",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Great Grand Childern 1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Children2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Grand Childern 1",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Great Grand Childern 1"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                 }
             ]
          }
      ]
   }
]
```

Solution without Python3.8 assignment expression:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def to_tree(d):
   _d = defaultdict(list)
   for a, *b in d:
     _d[a].append(b)
   vals = [[a, list(filter(None, b))] for a, b in _d.items()]
   return [{'name':a, 'children':to_tree(b)} if b else {'name':a} for a, b in vals]
```

Comment: line : return [{'name':a, 'children':to_tree(k)} if (k:=list(filter(None, b))) else \
                    {'name':a} for a, b in _d.items()] is not working , its throwing me syntax error at 'k'

Comment: @ImSanjay `k` is used in an assignment expression, which is only available in Python3.8. Please see my recent edit, as I added a solution that will be compatible with < Python3.8 versions.

Comment: still its throwing an error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'"

Comment: can we add column name after 'name' attribute? @Ajax1234

Answer (score 0):

As an intermediate step, you may want to convert your list of lists (which is currently not in the structure of a tree, but rather specifies individual vertical branches of the tree) to a tree of dicts where each node contains references to all of its child nodes.

Using a dict to build your tree from your list of lists makes it considerably simpler to make sure that all of the children of any given node end up in the right place (i.e. grouped together under that node):

```
>>> data = [
    ['root', 'Parent1', 'Children1', 'Grand Childern 1', 'Great Grand Childern 1'],
    ['root', 'Parent1', 'Children2', 'Grand Childern 1', 'Great Grand Childern 1'],
    ['root', 'Parent1', 'Children2', 'Grand Childern 2', 'Great Grand Childern 1'],
    ['root', 'Parent2', 'Children1', 'Grand Childern 1', 'Great Grand Childern 1'],
    ['root', 'Parent2', 'Children2', 'Grand Childern 1', 'Great Grand Childern 1']
]
>>> tree = {}
>>> for row in data:
...     node = tree
...     for cell in row:
...         node = node.setdefault(cell, {})
...
>>> tree
{'root': {
    'Parent1': {
        'Children1': {
            'Grand Childern 1': {
                'Great Grand Childern 1': {}
            }
        }, 
        'Children2': {
            'Grand Childern 1': {
                'Great Grand Childern 1': {}
            }, 
            'Grand Childern 2': {
                'Great Grand Childern 1': {}
            }
        }
    }, 
    'Parent2': {
        'Children1': {
            'Grand Childern 1': {
                'Great Grand Childern 1': {}
            }
        }, 
        'Children2': {
            'Grand Childern 1': {
                'Great Grand Childern 1': {}
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Now that you have everything in a structure that's an actual tree, it should be simple to convert it into whatever more specific format you need (e.g. the desired JSON).

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have to be from the "Pandas" library you can use the '[anytree](https://pypi.org/project/anytree/)' library to create your tree, and '[JSON Exporter](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exporter/jsonexporter.html)' to export it to JSON.